# Calling the same function within try except statement

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I want to simulate a procedure as follows:

- A secondary user requests for a server (1)
- If there is any available one, he will start using the server (2)
- If there is no Primary User arriving, he can complete his session on the server and then leaves. (3)
- If there is any Primary User arriving, that Secondary User will be kicked out of the server and go back to the queue, start again from (1).

This procedure may repeats infinitely unless he can have a complete session without termination and leave.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
class secondary_user(object):
   def procedure_SU(self, env):
      with servers.request as req:
        try:
           Request a server
           Transmit a server
           Complete and leave
        except Interrupt:
           Session is terminated and the user returns back to the queue
           with servers.request as req:
             try:
                Request a server
                Transmit a server
                Complete and leave
             except Interrupt:
                Session is terminated and the user returns back to the queue 
                .....
```

This is kinda calling the same procedure inside the `except` statement. Therefore, I tried simplifying the above structure by recursion as below

```
class secondary_user(object):
    def procedure_SU(self, env):
       with servers.request as req:
         try:
            Request a server
            Transmit a server
            Complete and leave
         except Interrupt:
            Session is terminated and the user returns back to the queue
            return self.procedure_SU(env)
```

However, the latter code seems not to work properly. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is your expected and received output ? Btw, be carefull with recursives; you are not exiting the first function when your start the second. It's only when the second finishes that the first finishes.

Comment: Use `while` loop and break if try block is successful or else it repeats